# Problem when downloading ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, download-speed

I tried to download Ubuntu 10.04 LTS but i took a very long time (it stated, '1 day left') so I cancelled the download process..or maybe I did it incorrectly. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you know what your Internet connection speed is? If you're on dial-up, for example, it may be better to [order some CDs](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/cds) or have a friend download and burn it for you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people were downloading Ubuntu 10.10 on the same server where you tried to download Ubuntu 10.04, maybe that the reason or maybe your connection is too slow. Either way the best solution for you is to use Bittorrent download, here are the torrents for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS :

[Ubuntu 10.04.3 Desktop 32-Bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

[Ubuntu 10.04.3 Desktop 64-Bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

The others versions are here : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#bt

Answer (score 1):

Provide detail of INTERNET speed and rights

There is problem with INTERNET not Ubuntu site. It depend on your inter speed and local permission .

Comment: There is no problem with Internet, Internet is fine. Don't accuse the Internet when there is a little problem with your connection, the Internet has been working all over the world  for years now and it is working remarkably well. The problem isn't Internet it's this specific Internet access which are two different things.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood me i mean to says his INTERNET connection.

Comment: It is his connection which has the problem